# Core Data, CloudKit - Deduplication causes nil relationships

Tags: xcode, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I followed along apples Article for relevant store changes, mainly for data deduplication. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes

I also downloaded the Core Data / CloudKit Demo App which already has a deduplication process. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud

In the Demo project I observed that more often than not, Posts loose their relationship to Tags.
After some investigation I assume that this happens, when a Tag which has a relationship to a Post, gets deleted during the deduplication process, before the relevant Post was synced to the device.

When the Post now arrives on the device, its related Tag Object does no longer exist. Therefore it's also not possible to find the retained, deduped Tag-Object which should be connected to the Post.

I'm wondering why this was implemented that way in the Demo Project, as this really causes critical data loss.

I have also no Idea how to avoid it. In the Article, Apple recommends to use Core Datas tombstone to preserve some values of deleted objects. However, there is no further explaination.

It's also not implemented in the Demo project.

How do I restore lost relationships and how does the tombstone help with it?

Example:

Before it synced:

[image]

After it synced:

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Together with the Apple Developer Technical Support I investigated this issue and it turned out that there is currently only one solution to it.

The issue occurs when an object gets deleted in the dedup process, before it's related objects have been synced to the device. When later on the related object finally arrives, the relationship is already nullified.

Currently the only solution is to mark objects as deleted rather then actually deleting them during deduplication. In my case I created an Entity called 'Dedup' with a Date property.

Rather than deleting an object, I link it to a new Dedup object and save the date of deduplication. After a longer period of time (several months) I finally delete the objects when I'm certain that all relationships are established.

Currently Core Datas tombstone is only capable of storing properties and no relationships. I suggested to Apple to expand the capabilities to enable storing the object IDs of objects which were related upon deletion.

Case: FB10995925

Comment: Thanks @wildcard. Really helpful. Is the duplicate connected by one way or the other to the winner after you associate it to a Dedup object? In a scenario where a photo is downloaded after you marked a tag object as a Dedup, you still have to update the winner with this new downloaded photo that was previously attached to the duplicate (in this case, I guess the transaction will contain an update on the duplicate tag, and we should then update the winner).

Answer (score 1):

In their sample project [Sharing Core Data objects between iCloud users](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/sharing_core_data_objects_between_icloud_users#4195282), Apple now covers this situation. They added some code to handle the soft deletion of objects that are duplicates. To do so, they added a `deduplicatedDate` property on the `Tag` entity, then only remove the objects after some time. See the file `PersistenceController+Deduplicate.swift`. They also have to filter these objects marked as deduplicated from the UI (like in the `TaggingView.swift`).